# how could i make a mysql hierarchy to look like a windows folder/subfolder structure

Tags: php, ajax

I'm making a Knowledegebase

I have my categories such as:

ID | Parent_ID | NAME | LEVEL

i want to use ajax or something so that when i retrieve the results, it looks like a windows explorer folder like:

- Category 1

  - subcat a
  - subcat b
- Category 2

  - subcat a
  - subcat b

where clicking on the + will expand the folder. ive googled it but all i can find are directory listings, which is not what i want since these are mysql tables and not directories.

Any help would be grateful!

Comment: Some of those plugins will be generic tree visualisers. You will (_gasp_) need to write some of your own code to produce a structure, likely in JSON, for one of these plugins to use

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, perhaps in PHP, you need to write code that:

- queries the database
- iterates through the rows of the result
- builds up a hierarchical structure based on the parent-ids

It will look something like this:

```
$pointers = array();  //points to each subnode of the hierarchy by ID
$pointers[1] = array();
$query("SELECT ID, Parent_ID, NAME, LEVEL FROM tablename");
foreach($pdo->query($query) as $row){
    if(isset($pointers[$row['Parent_ID']])){
        //found the parent
        $newchild = array();
        $pointers[$row['Parent_ID']][$row['ID']] = &$newchild;
    }else{
        $newparent = array();
        $newchild = array();
        $pointers[$row['Parent_ID']] = &$newparent;
        $pointers[$row['Parent_ID']][$row['ID']] = &$newchild;
    }
}
```

And then, assuming that the object with `ID = 1` is the root node, the entire hierarchy can be accessed as:

```
$hierarchy = $pointers[1];
```

**warning: I haven't tested any of this**